# Implicit wait in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

We know that elements of web page sometimes loads faster & sometime slower. 
If I have given implicit wait for 20 seconds, and if the element gets loaded in 5 or 10 or 15 seconds...will the program still wait for whole 20 seconds to execute next command or it will cut short the wait for 5/10/15 seconds accordingly & continue with next command?

Comment: What do you mean 'implicit wait'?  You can wait until a control is visible, with a timeout, so that either the code returns early, or times out.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Did you read the docs? What does it say? Did you google anything? What did you read? What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: HI Jeff, I did refer to few websites which gives information about "implicit wait". I understood that implicit wait will be applicable for all elements, and explicit wait is applicable for a particular element. However my question was : If implicit wait is applied with 20 seconds as waiting duration, and if the first element gets loaded in 4 seconds, will the execution still wait for 20 seconds?? or will it start with next element after 4 seconds??

Answer (score 0):

Yes program will cut short the wait. It will wait till the element is found in both cases- whether it is implicit or explicit. 
Implicit wait that you are setting is a wait for all the statements. Explicit wait at other end is the wait for that particular statement.

So implicit wait- you have to set once. Explicit wait- you can set for as many statement (that are going to take significantly more time than implicit wait) as you want.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html

Comment: Hi Dhaval, thanks for the answer. I will try it very soon & let you know about the outcome. Thanks again.